# Hadoop installation/unistallation

Tags: hadoop

1.While starting hadoop service using start-all.sh , it prompts for
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)
How to supress this prompt as I am starting it through a script , right now I am using expect module , but I think there could be a much simpler way to do this.

2.In order to uninstall hadoop , how do I revert back the effect of following command ?
$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop namenode-format

Answer (score 0):

The prompt asking if you want to connect indicates that you did not set up your passwordless ssh keys properly. Look up the tutorial by Michael Noll (or any tutorial teaching how to set up Hadoop in pseudo distributed or fully distributed mode) and in particular make sure the permissions on the files are correct

For the second part, the format process just prepares the directories where the NameNode and DataNode keep their data. Deleting the directories reverses that. The location of the directories depends on you configuration.